# How do I pass a queryset to BaseInlineFormSet from inlineformset_factory

Tags: django, django-forms

I know that I can pass formset to `inlineformset_factory` and this by default takes BaseInlineFormSet.  I also know that `BaseInlineFormSet` can take a queryset as a parameter.  How do I connect the dots to allow me to pass in a queryset which is based on the request to the `BaseInlineFormSet`.

In short I want to do this.

```
base_qs = Inline_model.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
factory_kwargs = { formset=BaseInlineFormSet(queryset=base_qs) }
formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, Inline_model, **factory_kwargs())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW this was solved using the following method.  I shifted to using a class based view and using the [django-extra-views package](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views).  This seemlessly allowed me to override the `get_formset_kwargs` method with my own queryset.

```
class CompanyDetailView(InlineFormSetView):
    """Details of the Company Page"""
    model = Company
    inline_model = CompanyDocument
    fields=('document', 'description')
    can_delete=True
    extra = 1

    def get_formset_kwargs(self):
        """Limit the queryset to only those which I have"""
        qs = CompanyDocument.objects.filter(company=self.request.user.company,
                                            shared_company = self.object,)
        kwargs = super(CompanyDetailView, self).get_formset_kwargs()
        kwargs['queryset'] = qs
        return kwargs
```